# JUnit test on API Gateway in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, post, junit, api-gateway

I want to test the functionalities of the API Gateway that I have developed in Spring Boot but I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient.getApplication(String)" because "this.eurekaClient" is null
```

This is the APIGatewayApplication.java

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is the API Gateway class that I'm trying to test:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
@CrossOrigin
public class DecryptRequest {

    @Autowired
    private EurekaClient eurekaClient;

    @RequestMapping("/decryptJSON")
    public String decryptJSON(@RequestBody String json) {

        InstanceInfo service = eurekaClient
                .getApplication("DecryptService")
                .getInstances()
                .get(0);

        System.out.println(service);
        String hostName = service.getHostName();
        int port = service.getPort();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String jsonString = restTemplate.postForObject("http://" + hostName + ":" + port + "/decryptJSON", json, String.class);
        return jsonString;
    }
}
```

This is the test class that I have implemented:

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApiGatewayApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private static DecryptRequest request;

    @BeforeEach
    static void setUp() {
        //decryptRequest = new DecryptRequest();
    }

    @Test
    public static void sendDecryptJSON(){

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("username", "luca");
            json.put("json", "--- values ---");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String expectedResult ="Unit:";
        assertThat(String.valueOf(request.decryptJSON(json.toString())), containsString(expectedResult));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        setUp();
        sendDecryptJSON();
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you add @EnableEurekaClient annotation in ApiGatewayApplication main Spring Boot application class file?

Comment: Whats `decryptRequest` because its not in the test case? Also instead of manually running the app just use @SpringBootTest on the class with tests and then inject the beans you need in the test

Comment: @SANN3 I have EnableDiscoveryClient and it works that way, by the way I tried adding it but nothing has changed

Comment: Is it solved the problem ?

Comment: @Nadir I have the SpringBootTest notation in the test class, that was only a tentative

Comment: @SANN3 no I still get the problem

Comment: Please show the actual code, it's hard to figure out what might be the problem looking on that weird test case

Comment: @Nadir I have edited the post with the full code, thank you for your support

Comment: It fails because you manually create the decryptRequest object, it's deattached from the spring context you try to operate in. Use `@Autowired private DecryptRequest request` instead of manually creating it in the `@BeforeEach`

Comment: Also with @SpringBootTest you dont need to manually start the application so ```ApiGatewayApplication apiGatewayApplication = new ApiGatewayApplication();
        String args[] = {"prova"};
        apiGatewayApplication.main(args);``` can be removed

Comment: @Nadir Ok I have removed the manually start of the application and added the AutoWired notation as you suggested but I still get the error, I have edited the post, maybe I have done something wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242725/discussion-between-luca-and-nadir).